# Java - Extracting non duplicate words from PDF files

Tags: java, pdfbox, full-text-indexing

I wrote a simple program in Java using PDFBox to extract words from a PDF file. It reads the text from PDF and extract word by word.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("C:\\my.pdf"))) {

            if (!document.isEncrypted()) {

                PDFTextStripper tStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
                String pdfFileInText = tStripper.getText(document);
                String lines[] = pdfFileInText.split("\\r?\\n");
                for (String line : lines) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }

            }
        } catch (IOException e){
            System.err.println("Exception while trying to read pdf document - " + e);
        }
    }

}
```

Is there a way to extract the words without duplicates?

Comment: In general, you can use a Set<T> to achieve that, something like this: Set<String> words = new HashSet<String>(); then you can add each word to the set *set.add(word)*, it will ignore the duplicated word, after that you can go through the set again to get all the words that are non-duplicated words.

Comment: @NoEm How would that look in the code?

Comment: // hold all non-duplicated words
Set<String> uniqueWords = new HashSet<String>();
for (String line : lines) {
    String[] words = line.split(" ");
 for (String word : words) {
  uniqueWords.add(word.trim());
 }
}
// print all non-duplicated words
System.out.println("Non-duplicated words: ");
Iterator<String> it = uniqueWords.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
 System.out.println(it.next());
}

Comment: You could post it as an answer instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Split each line by `space` - `line.split(" ")`
2. Maintain a `HashSet` to hold these words and keep adding all the words to it.

HashSet by its nature will ignore the duplicates.

```
HashSet<String> uniqueWords = new HashSet<>();

for (String line : lines) {
  String[] words = line.split(" ");

  for (String word : words) {
    uniqueWords.add(word);
  }
}
```

Comment: So I need to create one ? How to extract words to Hashset then?

Comment: When i try to print uniqueWords, I could still see duplicates in each key

Comment: After storing in hashSet, would it be possible to store these "words" in a database like MYSQL for full text indexing?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to remove duplicates, then one way you can achieve it is by adding the array into a `java.util.Set`. So right now, what you just need to do is this:

```
Set<String> noDuplicates = new HashSet<>( Arrays.asList( lines ) );
```

No more duplicates.

Comment: How would I store these words in hash to MySQL table?

Comment: That's a different problem.